# Returning to the main menu of a java program without using method

Tags: java, loops, variables

I'm currently a newbie to programming. We were tasked to evaluate if the rows and columns intended for the two matrices are acceptable to perform the addition operation. And if invalid, we would display an appropriate message and repeat the process by asking the user whether to repeat the process or not. If the answer is no, control should be back to the main menu. We weren't allowed to use methods at the moment so I'm quite problematic with this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class matrixTransposition {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);

    int menu_choice;
    char case_choice;
    char case_choice2;
    boolean menu_repeat = true;
    boolean case_repeat = true;
    boolean check = true;
    boolean inCheck = true;
    int rows_A, columns_A;
    int rows_A2, columns_A2;

    int rows_S, columns_S;
    int rows_M, columns_M;


do{
        //main menu selection here
    
    
        System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
        menu_choice = src.next().charAt(0);

    
        switch(menu_choice){
            case '1':
            
            do{
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\t\tMatrix Addition");
                
                //First Matrix/Array

                System.out.print("\nFirst Matrix: Please enter number of rows: "); //asks the user to enter number of rows
                rows_A = src.nextInt(); 
                
                System.out.print("\nFirst Matrix: Please enter number of columns: "); //asks the user to enter number of columns
                columns_A = src.nextInt();

                int [][] firstMatrix_A = new int [rows_A][columns_A];
                int [][] secondMatrix_A = new int [rows_A][columns_A]; //declaring the arrays to be used
                int [][] sumMatrix_A = new int [rows_A][columns_A];

                //asks the user to enter values
                System.out.println("\nPlease enter values for first matrix: ");
                for(int i=0; i<rows_A; i++)
                    for(int j=0; j<columns_A; j++)
                    firstMatrix_A[i][j]=src.nextInt();

                //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
                //Second Matrix/Array
                do{
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
                    System.out.print("Second Matrix: Please enter number of rows: "); // asks the user to enter rows
                    rows_A2 = src.nextInt(); 
                    
                    System.out.print("\nSecond Matrix: Please enter number of columns: "); //asks the user to enter columns
                    columns_A2 = src.nextInt();

                    //validating if the 2nd matrix has the same length as the first matrix
                    if(rows_A2 != rows_A || columns_A2 != columns_A){
                        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Error! Input is not the same length as the First Matrix!");
                        System.out.print("Do you want to input again? [Y][N]: ");
                        case_choice2 = src.next().charAt(0);
                        
                        switch(case_choice2){
                            case 'Y':
                                check = true;   //if the user entered Y, the user would be able  
                                break;          //re-enter rows and columns for the 2nd matrix
                            case 'N':
                                check = false;          //if the user entered N, the user would be immediately brought
                                menu_repeat = true;      //back to the main menu selection
                                break;
                            case 'y':
                                check = true;       //if the user entered Y, the user would be able
                                break;              //re-enter rows and columns for the 2nd matrix
                            case 'n':
                                menu_repeat = true;     //if the user entered N, the user would be immediately brought
                                check = false;          //back to the main menu selection
                                break;      
                            default:                    //if the user did not enter Y or N, the user would be ask to
                                                        //enter again.
                                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("Invalid Input Please Try Again....");
            
                            while(case_repeat){
                                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.print("Try Again? [Y][N]: ");
                                case_choice2 = src.next().charAt(0);
            
                                switch(case_choice2){
                                    case 'Y':
                                        check = true;               //if the user entered Y, the user would be able 
                                        case_repeat = false;        //re-enter rows and columns for the 2nd matrix
                                        break;
                                    case 'N':
                                        check = false;               //if the user entered N, the user would be immediately brought
                                        case_repeat = false;         //back to the main menu selection
                                        menu_repeat = true;
                                        break;
                                    case 'y':
                                        check = true;                //if the user entered y, the user would be able
                                        case_repeat = false;          //re-enter rows and columns for the 2nd matrix
                                        break;
                                    case 'n':
                                        check = false;              //if the user entered n, the user would be immediately brought
                                        case_repeat = false;        //back to the main menu selection
                                        menu_repeat = true;
                                        break;
                                    default:                        //if the user did not enter Y or N, the user would be ask to
                                                                    //enter again.
                                        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
                                        System.out.println("Invalid Input Please Try Again....");
                                        case_repeat = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }      
                    }
                        //else if all inputs are valid the program would proceed to the next step
                    else{
                    
                    //asks the user to enter values
                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter values for second matrix: ");
                    for(int i=0; i<rows_A2; i++)
                        for(int j=0; j<columns_A2; j++)
                            secondMatrix_A[i][j]=src.nextInt();
                            check = false;
                    }
                }while(check);
            
                //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                for(int i=0; i<rows_A; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<columns_A; j++)
                sumMatrix_A[i][j] = firstMatrix_A[i][j] + secondMatrix_A[i][j]; //adds the two matrices

                System.out.println("------------------------------------");     //displays the first matrix
                System.out.println("First Matrix");
                for(int i=0; i<rows_A; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<columns_A; j++){
                        System.out.print(firstMatrix_A[i][j] + "  ");    
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

                System.out.println("------------------------------------");     //displays the second matrix
                System.out.println("Second Matrix");
                for(int x=0; x<rows_A2; x++){
                    for(int y=0; y<columns_A2; y++){
                        System.out.print(secondMatrix_A[x][y] + "  ");    
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

                System.out.println("------------------------------------");     //displays the sum of the two matrices
                System.out.println("Matrix Sum");
                for(int i=0; i<rows_A; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<columns_A; j++){
                        System.out.print(sumMatrix_A[i][j] + "  ");    
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                
                System.out.print("Do you want to try again? [Y][N]: ");         //asks the user to re-run the operation
                case_choice = src.next().charAt(0);
            }while(case_choice == 'Y' || case_choice == 'y');                   //if yes the operation would re-run
            
            if(case_choice == 'N' || case_choice == 'n'){                       //if no, the user would be brought back to the
                menu_repeat = true;                                             //main menu selection
            }
        
            break;
             }

          }while(menu_repeat); 
       }
      }
```

Comment: where are you stuck, are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm getting an error. During the first Y and N choices, every time the user inputs the character N, the user must be brought back to the main menu. But in my case, it still continues down the code and it gives me an error

Comment: Hi @Ivy, Can you edit the post with that information so it makes your post clearer?

Comment: @Sergio here, I've added some comments explaining each function. The error I'm getting is inside the switch statements found in the validation of the second matrix length. If the user entered N or n, it doesn't go back to the main menu selection. Instead it continues the code and returns an error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the user enters N, you are breaking out of the inner loop. What you want is to break out of the loop where you are displaying menu choices, i.e., the outer most loop.

Your code structure is as follows:

```
do{
    //main menu selection here
    switch (menu_choice) {
            case '1':
                do {
                    //First Matrix/Array
                    //Second Matrix/Array
                    do {
                        //compare matrix and prompt for input if rows and col dont match
                        case_choice2 = src.next().charAt(0);

                        switch (case_choice2) {
                            case 'N':
                            check = false;
                            menu_repeat = true;
                            break;
                            .
                            .
                            .
                         }
                   }
            }
       }
}
```

Your break statement breaks out of the inner loop. Whereas you want to break out to the outer most loop.

You should use labels for this purpose:

```
do{
        //main menu selection here
        //define label here
        main_menu:
        switch (menu_choice) {

            .
            .
            .
                 switch (case_choice2) {
                                case 'N':
                                check = false;
                                menu_repeat = true; 
                                //label used here
                                break main_menu;

            .
            .
            .
```

This will break out to the loop of your choice. You can also use continue, if you want to pass the control back to the loop.

Please note: You might want to re consider the usage of the case_choice variable because it will no longer be always accessible outside the loop, as you are breaking out of it. The compiler will for sure give you an error for the same.